# C# template could not down cast child type

Tags: c#

I am trying to define EntityType is the base class of ViewModel, and within the Save method I want to upcast the ViewModel instance to EntityType and save to DBContext. However, the line of code _DbContext.Add((EntityType)vm); does't do the casting. How do I fix it?

```
    public class ReportDefinitionDetailsController : BaseDataController<ReportDefinitionDetail, int, ReportDefinitionDetailsViewModel>{}

    public abstract class BaseDataController<EntityType, Key, ViewModel>
        where ViewModel : EntityType, new()
        where EntityType : AuditTrail, new()
    {
        public void Save(ViewModel vm)
        {
             _DbContext.Add((EntityType)vm);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", it's quite useful for you to explain what "doesn't work" means, as we can't see your screen from where we are, and mind reading across unknown distances is often not reliable. Do you get a compiler error? Does it just not save properly? Is there a different issue? Please [edit] your question to provide more details about what's "not working". If you provide us with the information, it's much easier for us to help you get an answer. Thanks. :-)

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. ViewModel IMPLEMENTS EntityType so its not a down cast but an up cast.

Comment: Mr Universe sry used the wrong word

Answer (score 0):

Two possible scenarios I can think of here:

1. _DbContext.Add() is expecting a parameter of a type that derives from AuditTrail, but not AuditTrail specifically. You would be getting a compile error like: cannot convert from 'EntityType' to 'DerivedEntity'.
2. _DbContext.Add() is expecting an AuditTrail reference but is then trying to convert the passed object in a manner that won't work. For example, it is passed AuditTrailDerivedClass1 and attempts to cast to AuditTrailDerivedClass2.

The principle: Just because class A and class B both derive from class C, does not mean that A can be cast as B.

Comment: My bad. All EntityType inherit from the AuditTrail as well, but is irrelevant to current problem I believe. So the hierarchy is AuditTrail <- EntityType <- ViewModel

Comment: @BryanFok, that doesn't really change much (possibly makes it worse). I'm guessing it's the compile-time error (1)?

Comment: Exception is : Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'FTAccounting.MVC.Models.ReportDefinitionDetailsViewModel'. But doesnt matter you see, the problem is it doesn't cast the type at the first place, and I am wondering why

Comment: Ah, I see. What you're doing isn't going to work (as you've discovered). Your code is doing an implicit conversion between the object references because ViewModel derives from EntityType (AuditTrail). I'd say you would have to provide your own conversion logic depending on what your entity mappings are.